# mouseup event not firing in d3

Tags: d3.js

I am registering mousedown,mouseup and d3 drag behaviour on `svg g` using mousedown and mouseup events i will create link between 2 nodes i.e mouseup node and mousedown node.

Previously in v3 , mouseup event was properly working. but in `d3v4`, i am not getting call for mouseup event instead getting call in dragend event as shown in code below.

- why i am not getting mouseup event call and how to solve it?

i searched in d3 related  forums but i couldn't find any solutions.

**UPDATE**

I will click from one circle and drop the line on another circle,using the mousedown event i will be able to get dom of one circle.how to get the dom of other circle(i.e mouseup while dropping the line). dragevent only gives the clicked node dom.

There is a solution for getting the element under mouse position in dragend but in my project i cannot use that solution.

- so is there a way to trigger mouseup event so that i can get the correct dom on native event ?

Below is the working snippet.

```js
thisGraph = this;
    thisGraph.drag = d3.drag()
        .on("drag", function (a,aa,aaa) {
            thisGraph.dragLine.attr("class","dragline")
            var circ = aaa[0]
            thisGraph.dragLine.attr('d', 'M' + $(aaa[0]).attr("cx") + ',' + $(aaa[0]).attr("cy") + 'L' + d3.event.sourceEvent.clientX + ',' + d3.event.sourceEvent.clientY);

        })
        .on("end", function (data,index,dom) {

            thisGraph.dragLine.attr("class","")
            console.log("drag end called",dom)

        });
    var svg = d3.select('#svgnow');
    svg.attr("height","500px");
    svg.attr("width","500px")

    thisGraph.dragLine = svg.append('svg:path')
        .attr("class","dragline")
        .attr('d', 'M0,0L0,0')
        .style('marker-end', 'url(#mark-end-arrow)');

    var circle = svg.append("circle")
        .attr("cx",100)
        .attr("cy",100)
        .attr("r",20)
        .style("fill","blue")
        .on("mousedown",function (d,index,dom) {
            console.log("mousedown event called....",dom)
        })
        .on("mouseup",function (d,index,dom) {
            console.log("mouseup event called....",dom)
        })
        .call(thisGraph.drag);


    var circle2 = svg.append("circle")
        .attr("cx",200)
        .attr("cy",100)
        .attr("r",20)
        .style("fill","red")
        .on("mousedown",function (d,index,dom) {
            console.log("mousedown event called....",dom)
        })
        .on("mouseup",function (d,index,dom) {
            console.log("mouseup event called....",dom)
        })
        .call(thisGraph.drag);
```

```css
  path.dragline{
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <svg id="svgnow" style="border:2px solid red;">
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I think `d3.event.sourceEvent.target` is what you are looking for. Have a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/6er0az53/.

Comment: Great thanks ! this is what i'm looking for and it would be more helpful if i am able to get `data  of d3.event.sourceEvent.target` @altocumulus

Comment: Just wrap that element in a D3 selection and call `.data` to retrieve any datum previously bound to that element: `d3.select(d3.event.sourceEvent.target).data()`.

Comment: Nice solution so far. but how do you get the target circle? In the drag end function, the dom is always the one of the source circle. (I used your example code)